# Determine if file is a directory, inside zip archive

Tags: c, header, zip, file-format

I read zip files according to the specification, and get information for each file, from a central directory. From the headers I read:

```
#define VERSION_NEEDED_OFSSET 6

UINT16 versionNeeded = (UINT16)*(zipFile + VERSION_NEEDED_OFSSET);
```

So I zipped some files, and also a few directories, and when I got info about the directory, I got `versionNeeded = 0x000a`

From the documentation I read:

> The minimum supported ZIP specification version needed 
>       to extract the file, mapped as above.  This value is based on 
>       the specific format features a ZIP program MUST support to 
>       be able to extract the file.  If multiple features are
>       applied to a file, the minimum version MUST be set to the 
>       feature having the highest value. New features or feature 
>       changes affecting the published format specification will be 
>       implemented using higher version numbers than the last 
>       published value to avoid conflict.
>
> 4.4.3.2 Current minimum feature versions are as defined below:
>
> 1.0 - Default value
>
> 1.1 - File is a volume label
>
> 2.0 - File is a folder (directory)

But what is the part of the zip header that is used to determine the file type? I cannot see any types or bits that are responsible for the file type from the [documentation](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).

Comment: As far as I can tell, the various Zip utilities store them as zero-length entries with filenames ending with '/'. Perhaps that's enough?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok. If anyone finds this, the right way to do this is to check the offset at central directory start plus **38**, a field called **external file attributes**

From the documentation:

> 4.4.15 external file attributes: (4 bytes) The mapping of the external attributes is host-system dependent (see 'version made by'). For
>   MS-DOS, the low order byte is the MS-DOS directory attribute byte. If
>   input came from standard input, this field is set to zero.

```
UINT32 external_attributes = (UINT32)*(zipFile + 38);
```

Then you match this value against [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117(v=vs.85).aspx) constants from MSDN.

To match a directory, compare the `external_attributes` like so:

```
if(external_attributes == 0x10) //FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY
```

Comment: This seems incomplete the way I read it. External file attributes are host-system dependent. So the byte at offset 38 can only be interpreted this way if the byte at offset 4 is 0 for FAT/MS-DOS/etc. If the byte at offset 4 is 3 then the field at offset 38 will need to be interpreted in a different way. Same if it is anything other than 0 or 3. Then again, other sources do seem to suggest this field contains both DOS and UNIX values?

Comment: 7-Zip (LGPL) source code at https://7-zip.org/download.html has an implementation of IsDir under CPP/7zip/Archive/Zip/ZipItem.cpp

Comment: Why didnt zip just have a custom flag for this?. Zip is such a dumb file format.