# Get Directory Entries in a ZIP File

Tags: java, zip

I'm writing a Java program which given a qualified-name (like: `java.lang.String`), fetches and returns the corresponding entry from the `src.zip` file in the JDK for further processing.

So far my program works fine for any qualified-name which refers to a specific `.java` source file; but I'm having trouble when the qualified-name refers to a whole package (like: `java.util.*`). In this case I want my program to return a listing of all entries in the given package.

The problem is it seems there's no way to (efficiently) do such a thing using the utilities provided in the `java.util.zip.*` package! I have tried both `ZipFile` and `ZipInputStream` and none recognize the directories in the `src.zip` file! They only return entries for individual `.java` source files!

In code language, both:

```
ZipEntry entry;
ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream("src.zip"));
while((entry = zip.getNextEntry()) != null) 
    System.out.println(entry.isDirectory());
```

and:

```
Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> zip = new ZipFile("src.zip").entries();
while (zip.hasMoreElements()) {
    ZipEntry entry = zip.nextElement();
    System.out.println(entry.isDirectory());
}
```

always return false; no directories at all!

Even the following code is useless and just returns `null` (which means `Not Found`):

```
ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile("src.zip");
zipfile.getEntry("java/util/");
```

A work-around is to use either of the two iterations I listed above and perform an exhaustive search for the desired entries:

```
if (entry.getName().startsWith("java/util/"))
    System.out.println(entry);
```

But clearly this is not efficient! Is there no way to either retrieve the entry of a directory in the `src.zip` file or to efficiently list the entries for a given directory path? Note that I want to directly process the ZIP file without extraction (for obvious reasons).

---

#### Update

As it's apparent from the discussion under *Timothy Truckle*'s answer, the above results were achieved using the `src.zip` file from the latest Oracle JDK at the time of this writing (i.e. JDK-8 update-111). The results differ when using another `src.zip` file from a different JDK version (e.g. JDK-7 update-80). The credit goes to *marabu* for pointing out the `unzip -l` utility in the comments.

#### Note

While the problem of retrieving directory entries is solved, the problem of *efficiently* retrieving the list of entries contained inside a given directory path of a ZIP file is not solved. Yet the case is still closed, since according to *Timothy Truckle*'s answer, this cannot be done in any other way than an exhaustive search in the entries, due to limitations of the ZIP format.

Comment: AFAIK, zip entries are just a bunch of full path `/foo/bar/lol/a.txt` etc and you don't necessarily have a `/foo/bar/lol/` `/foo/bar/` `/foo/` in that case. So I think you have no choice but to iterate everything

Comment: @RC. So your saying that it's related to this specific `src.zip` file? Because I've seen other ZIP files which do have entries for directories.

Comment: See [https://stackoverflow.com/q/39290157/645511](this answer) for what appears to be a more robust way of doing this. tl;dr, check the "external file attributes" field for the presence of flag 0x10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> @RC. So your saying that it's related to this specific src.zip file?  Because I've seen other ZIP files which do have entries for directories. – Seyed Mohammad

No and Yes. The [ZIP file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Structure) does only know of files but not directories.

What you may have seen in other zip files is that they included a zero length file named `.` for each (sub-) folder. But it is not required nor default to do so.

But even if this special entries exist you could not handle them as folders within the ZIP directly (even that all files in the same subfolder are listed consecutively is by accident and neither required nor implied).

Comment: Then I guess this concludes the answer to my question: "What I'm asking for is a limitation of the ZIP format, and not a limitation of the Java ZIP API. Hence, there is no other solution but the exhaustive search."  Case closed.

Comment: Every zip file contains all the necessary directory entries to rebuild a filesystem structure as long as you don't use option `zip -D`.  Use `unzip -l` to find out if directory entries are present in your zip file.  You can recognize directory entries by a trailing path delimiter.

Comment: @marabu I checked the `unzip -l` command on the `src.zip` file, and it did print some zero-length entries for several directories; including: `java/net/`, `java/lang/`, `java/util/` and many more. Yet as I explained in the question, none of these were detected via the Java ZIP API. So what does this mean?

Comment: @marabu **CORRECTION:** I tested the `unzip -l` on a different `src.zip` file from Oracle JDK-7u80, while the initial tests were done on the `src.zip` file from Oracle JDK-8u111. Running the above Java code on this file also finds the directory entries! I guess it really was related to that specific `src.zip` file! According to the output of `unzip -l` on the `src.zip` file from Oracle JDK-8u111, there are no zero-length directory entries, and consistent with the Java ZIP API output.